# Different results when I define references to same variable in different ways

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, g++

I defined a class like this

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a, int b):a(a),b(b){}
    void test(const char* name) {cout<<name<<": "<<a<<"  "<<b<<endl;}
public:
    int a,b;
};
```

then the main function:

```
int main()
{
    A obj(1,2);
    A& ref_1=obj;
    A& ref_2=obj;
    ref_1.a = 2;
    ref_1.test("ref_1");
    ref_2.test("ref_2");
    cout<<&obj<<endl<<&ref_1<<endl<<&ref_2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the result, as I expect, is

```
ref_1: 2  2
ref_2: 2  2
0x7fff59bb0c90
0x7fff59bb0c90
0x7fff59bb0c90
```

However, when I define two references like this:

```
    A& ref_1=obj, ref_2=obj;
```

the result is very strange:

```
ref_1: 2  2
ref_2: 1  2
0x7fff58a68c90
0x7fff58a68c90
0x7fff58a68c80
```

I use g++ as my compiler.
Can anyone tell me why this thing happened?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/428c1c5ca5366493

Comment: When you are defining as `A& ref_1=obj, ref_2=obj;` the compiler take it as `A &ref_1 = obj; A ref_2 = obj;`

Comment: Another example that might help: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3b5ef2e046665b2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A& ref_1=obj, ref_2=obj;
```

is equivalent to

```
A& ref_1=obj;
A ref_2=obj;
```

If you want both to be references, you need to write

```
A &ref_1=obj, &ref_2=obj;
```

Alternatively, avoid this confusion altogether, and just write

```
A& ref_1=obj;
A& ref_2=obj;
```

like you did originally.

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter whether the space is on the left or right of the `&` symbol. You can even use space on both sides, or none at all.

Comment: And this is a good argument for the style: `MyType &myRef`/`MyType *myPtr` instead of `MyType& myRef`/`MyType* myPtr` so that it's super-obvious as to what type each variable is in a comma-list of variables.

Answer (score 2):

When you write it as `A& ref_1=obj, ref_2=obj;` it's as if you wrote it as

```
A& ref_1=obj;
A ref_2=obj;
```

If you want to write it on one line and have both of them be references you'll need to write it as

`A &ref_1=obj, &ref_2=obj;`

Answer (score 2):

You've fallen afoul of one of precedence.

While what you've written reads as "declare ref_1 and ref_2 as type ref-to-A", the `&` actually binds to the variable not the type. The same thing happens with pointers. This is why there is some ongoing debate about which is the more correct way to write references/pointers.

```
A& ref_1; // ref_1 is a reference to type A.
A &ref_1; // means the same thing.

A& ref_1, ref_2;
A &ref_1, ref_2; // same as above.
A &ref_1, &ref_2; // what you thought the first line mean't

A* p1, p2; // p1 is a pointer, p2 is an instance of A
A *p1, *p2; // what you actually intended on the previous line.
```